# Send btimap to another activity

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

I am trying to send an image to an activity from my ercyclerview fragment now i dont know how to do this. Newbie().
This is my adaptor

```
    @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.r_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Place place = new PlaceData().propertyList().get(position);
    holder.homeTextView.setText(place.name);
    holder.address.setText(place.addressname);
    holder.prices.setText(place.prices);

    //loading image to the main home imageview
    Picasso.with(mcontext).load(path).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.mainImageview);

    holder.mainImageview.

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return new PlaceData().propertyList().size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public LinearLayout mainHolder;
    public LinearLayout placeNameHolder;
    public ImageView mainImageview;
    public TextView homeTextView, address, prices;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mainImageview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeImage);
        placeNameHolder = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeNameHolder);
        mainHolder = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainHolder);
        homeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
        address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.propertyaddress);
        prices = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceid);
        mainHolder.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (itemClickListener != null) {

            itemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getPosition());
        }
    }
}

public interface onItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(final onItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;

}
```

and this my fragment

```
    //oclick listener for the recylerview in the fragment
MainAdaptor.onItemClickListener OnItemClickListener = new MainAdaptor.onItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Details.class);
        intent.putExtra(Details.EXTRA_PARAM_ID,position);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

What i want to do this that, when the recyclerview item is clicked is goes the activity imageview

Answer (score 1):

in `RecyclerView` add this code

```
   //Convert to byte array
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), act.class);
  intent.putExtra("Image", byteArray /*byte[]*/);
  //View v
  v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second one add this :

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
//or whatever
```

but seems you have Path (String) in `RecyclerView` in that case add this lines of code in `RecyclerView`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("Image", Image);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

in second activity add this

```
String UrlImage = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Image");

final ImageView Header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(UrlImage)
                .error(RandomClass.HeaderImage())
                .into(Header);
```

Comment: Where do i place the second code snippet in the recyclerview

Comment: if you mean `getIntent` part just add it in second Activity thats it (fill it with correct data of cause) or you mean `Intent` **String** just create Path variable (`private String path;`)  and put `Intent` where you have `ClickListener` like `onItemClick` and  `please be more clear about your problem`

Comment: thank you i have managed to it, i am new at android so sometimes my problems are a bit abstract i will try to more specific. Thanks again